# Error loading Python lib with PyInstaller on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I am trying to package some python into an executable on MacOS (10.14.5). I am able to create the executable, but executing the resulting `dist/hello_world` executable gives the following error:

```
[55240] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/yh/6_6mb2y96kg0gnb_nh9r2zrr0000gp/T/_MEIwUMw4X/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/yh/6_6mb2y96kg0gnb_nh9r2zrr0000gp/T/_MEIwUMw4X/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/yh/6_6mb2y96kg0gnb_nh9r2zrr0000gp/T/_MEIwUMw4X/Python: code signature invalid for '/var/folders/yh/6_6mb2y96kg0gnb_nh9r2zrr0000gp/T/_MEIwUMw4X/Python'
```

My machine is running Python 3.7.7 installed from using the Mac installer downloaded from https://www.python.org/

For now, the script I am trying to package only contains `print('hello world!')` and the packaging command I am using is `pyinstaller -F hello_world.py`

Answer (score 2):

I had success using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and installing the specific version of python with the enable framework option:

`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.7.6`

With this version of python (set using the command `pyenv local 3.7.6` in the folder where hello_world.py is located), install pyinstaller (and any other modules you need) with `pip`.  Then build with

`pyinstaller hello_world.py --onefile --clean --windowed`

which should give you a functioning `dist/hello_word`.  As a python fledgling, I have no idea why this works as opposed to the steps in the original question. (I thought the Mac OS installer included the Python.framework by default -- I'm sure my ignorance is exposed here as this probably differs significantly from what the `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` variable is doing above).

Also possible to do all this within a virtual environment (easily managed by [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Pyinstaller only supports Python 2.7, 3.5–3.7. If you downgrade to Python 3.7 it will work!

Comment: Thanks Robin. I am using 3.7.7 and the problem is still there

Comment: @A.Pine Try switching back to Python 3.7, that version did work for me while 3.7.7. still gave this problem

Comment: Am running python 3.7 and still getting this issue

Comment: @Shaw The cause could be different now that they've updated PyInstaller. So I don't know anything about the current situation unfortunately.