# Error loading Python lib pyinstaller (detailed description of different attempts taken)

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

Error loading Python lib
The name of my python script is kled.py

**This is the message I used to create it:**

pyinstaller kled.py --windowed
Here is the error message I get when I execute the terminal file located in dist-->(a folder called kled)-->(executable terminal file called kled)

```
[3173] Error loading Python lib '/Users/john/Documents/chill.py/kledfinal/dist/kled/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/john/Documents/chill.py/kledfinal/dist/kled/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/john/Documents/chill.py/kledfinal/dist/kled/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/john/Documents/chill.py/kledfinal/dist/kled/Python'
```

When I double click the application it has created it appears to open in my dock, and then goes away, nothing actually opens.

**Here are the resources I've already looked at but didn't find success from:**

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2150

- I don't understand the solution they found. The two people troubleshooting didn't explain the steps they were taking so I couldn't follow.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3499

- This is where I got the idea to change my spec files, because in his pyinstaller command it seems like he has a specific spec file he was trying to use.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

- I thought maybe I could edit my spec file to include the modules or python version it might be missing, but no other results told me how to properly set up my spec file to do this. I was originally trying to use py2app and if any of you know it, you will know that setup.py basically lets you hand pick all the files and stuff you need. Unfortunately py2app has a huge amount of issues in general so I decided my error wasn't going to get fixed, but pyinstaller seems to have some experts so maybe you guys can help.

[Error loading Python lib with PyInstaller on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678697/error-loading-python-lib-with-pyinstaller-on-macos)

- went through the steps and it just didn't work for me. Same outcome where the application doesn't work and the executable terminal file called kled says that it had an Error loading python lib.

**RESOURCES YOU MIGHT NEED (idk I'm just guessing but here is some stuff)**

**my kled.spec file:**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['kled.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/john/Documents/chill.py/kledfinal'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='kled',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='kled.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)


**Python version:**

Python 3.8.2
```

**Modules I am trying to use:**

pygame
time
random
sys
os
pickle

**MacOS version:**

macOS Catalina

Version 10.15.4

**My warn-kled.txt file:**

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by setuptools._vendor.six (conditional), numpy.testing._private.utils (conditional), numpy.lib.utils (delayed, conditional), numpy.lib.format (delayed, conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional), py._io.capture (optional)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named 'win32com.shell' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named nt - imported by os (delayed, conditional, optional), ntpath (optional), shutil (conditional), pathlib (conditional), ctypes (delayed, conditional)
missing module named win32api - imported by distutils.msvccompiler (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named win32com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pygame.sysfont (conditional), numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (delayed, conditional, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional), pygments.formatters.img (optional)
missing module named winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), mimetypes (optional), urllib.request (delayed, conditional, optional), pygame.sysfont (conditional), distutils.msvccompiler (optional), distutils.msvc9compiler (top-level), distutils._msvccompiler (top-level), numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (delayed, conditional, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional), pygments.formatters.img (optional)
missing module named netbios - imported by uuid (delayed)
missing module named win32wnet - imported by uuid (delayed)
missing module named _winapi - imported by encodings (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (optional), test.support (delayed, conditional), multiprocessing.connection (optional), multiprocessing.spawn (delayed, conditional), multiprocessing.reduction (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional), multiprocessing.heap (conditional), multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32 (top-level), asyncio.windows_events (top-level), asyncio.windows_utils (top-level)
missing module named msvcrt - imported by subprocess (optional), getpass (optional), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional), multiprocessing.spawn (delayed, conditional), multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32 (top-level), asyncio.windows_events (top-level), asyncio.windows_utils (top-level), numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.urlretrieve - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._php_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.FancyURLopener - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._sourcemod_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.urlopen - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._postgres_builtins (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._lua_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib (delayed), py._path.svnwc (delayed)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by numpy.core.numerictypes (conditional), numpy.core.numeric (conditional), numpy.lib.function_base (conditional), numpy.lib._iotools (conditional), numpy.ma.core (conditional), numpy.distutils.misc_util (delayed, conditional), numpy (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), py._builtin (conditional), ptyprocess.ptyprocess (optional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named _overlapped - imported by asyncio.windows_events (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named win32evtlog - imported by logging.handlers (delayed, optional)
missing module named win32evtlogutil - imported by logging.handlers (delayed, optional)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources.py31compat (top-level)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named 'multiprocessing.forking' - imported by /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py (optional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cStringIO (top-level), numpy.core (conditional), pygame (conditional)
missing module named 'pygame._view' - imported by pygame (delayed)
missing module named OpenGL - imported by pygame (delayed)
missing module named numpy.uint32 - imported by numpy (top-level), pygame._numpysurfarray (top-level)
missing module named commands - imported by numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (conditional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.packaging - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.six' - imported by setuptools (top-level), setuptools.extension (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.version' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filterfalse - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filter - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.ordered_set - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.sdist (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.utils' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.tags' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named wincertstore - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named backports - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' - imported by 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.pyparsing' - imported by setuptools._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), setuptools._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.winreg - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (conditional), setuptools.msvc (conditional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.map - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level)
runtime module named setuptools.extern.six.moves - imported by setuptools.dist (top-level), configparser (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.command.setopt (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level), 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.monkey (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.py27compat (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), setuptools.wheel (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.command.sdist (top-level), setuptools.command.bdist_egg (top-level), setuptools.unicode_utils (top-level), setuptools.installer (top-level), setuptools.command.develop (top-level)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.command' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy_distutils - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, optional)
missing module named __svn_version__ - imported by numpy.f2py.__version__ (optional)
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named ConfigParser - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (conditional), numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config (conditional)
missing module named win32con - imported by distutils.msvccompiler (optional)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional)
missing module named twisted - imported by _pytest.unittest (delayed)
missing module named zope - imported by _pytest.unittest (delayed)
missing module named py.process - imported by py (top-level), py._path.svnurl (top-level)
missing module named py.path - imported by py (top-level), py._path.svnurl (top-level), _pytest.doctest (top-level)
missing module named apipkg - imported by py (optional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by attr._compat (conditional)
missing module named chardet - imported by pygments.lexer (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named ctags - imported by pygments.formatters.html (optional)
missing module named PIL - imported by pygments.formatters.img (optional)
missing module named 'py.io' - imported by _pytest._io (top-level)
missing module named importlib_metadata - imported by pluggy.manager (conditional), _pytest.compat (conditional)
missing module named typing_extensions - imported by _pytest.outcomes (conditional), _pytest._code.code (conditional), _pytest._code.source (conditional), _pytest.config.argparsing (conditional), _pytest.runner (conditional), _pytest.main (conditional), _pytest.capture (conditional)
missing module named pathlib2 - imported by _pytest.pathlib (conditional)
missing module named colorama - imported by py._io.terminalwriter (conditional, optional), _pytest.capture (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named atomicwrites - imported by _pytest.assertion.rewrite (conditional)
missing module named argcomplete - imported by _pytest._argcomplete (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'py.builtin' - imported by py._io.terminalwriter (top-level)
missing module named compiler - imported by py._code._assertionold (top-level)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named scipy - imported by numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named nose - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional), numpy.testing._private.decorators (delayed), numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named win32pdh - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, conditional)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.lib.i0 - imported by numpy.lib (top-level), numpy.dual (top-level)
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (conditional, optional)
missing module named thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (conditional, optional)
missing module named cpickle - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named future_builtins - imported by numpy.lib.npyio (conditional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, conditional)
missing module named urlparse - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, conditional)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), pygame._numpysurfarray (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), pygame._numpysurfarray (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named 'pygame.scrap' - imported by pygame (optional)
missing module named 'pygame.movie' - imported by pygame (optional)
missing module named 'pygame.overlay' - imported by pygame (optional)
missing module named Queue - imported by pygame.threads (conditional)
missing module named Py25Queue - imported by pygame.threads (conditional)
missing module named 'pygame.cdrom' - imported by pygame (conditional, optional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by pygame.compat (conditional)
```

Comment: I'm no expert on this topic but have you tried renaming to `main.py` and removing second level imports? And I see you are using python 3.8. Do you also use pygame 2.0.0.dev6?

Comment: @kaktus-car That is the version of pygame I am using. Also I don't know what second level imports are, could you enlighten me so I can fix this?

Comment: For example in `file_b` you `import file_a` and now you also need `file_a` in `file_c`. Now if you just `import file_b` you will also `import file_a` indirectly. This is second level import and pyinstaller couldn't handle it. I repeat again, this was the case in the past, maybe it isn't now.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Pyinstaller(release3.6)just supports Python 2.7, 3.5–3.7

So, downgrade Python3.8 Everything is OK.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some clarity to the answer.